# How to update table with SqlAdapter.Update which doesn't have primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am having `SqlDataAdapter` in which I am updating `DataRow`.

I got exception

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information

The error goes if I put primary key in table.

But I don't want to put primary key in it.

```
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
var updatedRows = Getting some row ...
dataAdapter.Update(updatedRows);
```

Comment: Show your work as well..

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not really a table* - ***why*** do you ***insist*** on avoiding a primary key? It's the **most basic property** of any good database design!

Comment: @marc_s : As sql allow to create table without primary key. It means its a really table. I am writing a generic code. So i don't know whether the table has primary key or not. I am not putting generic code as it will be difficult to explain.

Comment: Make it your **primary habit** to ***ALWAYS*** define a primary key for any table! It's the first bullet point of the first slide on the first database normal form - embrace it!

Comment: @marc_s : i know that. But the method i am writing in which i can't change the definition of table

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is pretty simple.  To use the `DataAdapter` commands, you must have a primary key.   `EntityFramework` is the same way.  If you cannot or do not want to use a primary key, then you will need to issue your update statements as plain ol' SQL using ADO.NET rather than the `DataAdapter`.

Comment: @marc_s Here is a situation: Importing Excel spreadsheet 'data' and the only 'primary key' would require one that is longer than some random 900 byte limit Microsoft chose to impose. The world is large and complex, our experiences small and limited.

Answer (score 1):

Without a primary key, you won't be able to rely on the SqlCommandBuilder to generate the insert/update/delete commands for you.

If you still want to use the SqlDataAdapter to modify your data, you'll need to explicitly set the adapter's InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand properties.

This may help to get you started : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971491.aspx

EDIT: without a primary key, you're going to have to be very careful when modifying data. e.g. when the UPDATE sql is executed, it will be much easier to accidently update more than 1 row of the table for the DataRow. Having a primary key will make things easier and more robust.